# Meaning of $X$ in $f\colon X\to Y$

Tags: functions, notation

From the Wikipedia article on *Function (mathematics)*:

> A **function** is a process or a relation that associates **each** element $x$ of a set $X$, the **domain** of the function, to a single element $y$ of another set $Y$ (possibly the same set), the codomain of the function. (...)
>   The domain and codomain are not always explicitly given when a function is defined, and, without some (possibly difficult) computation, one knows only that the domain is contained in a larger set. Typically, this occurs in mathematical analysis, where "a function from $X$ to $Y$" often refers to a function that may have **a proper subset of $X$** as domain. For example, a "function from the reals to the reals" may refer to a real-valued function of a real variable, and this phrase does not mean that the domain of the function is the whole set of the real numbers, but only that the domain is a set of real numbers that contains a non-empty open interval; such a function is then called a **partial function**.

From the Wikipedia article on *Partial function*:

> In real and complex analysis, a partial function is generally called simply a **function**.

From the Wikipedia article on *Domain of a function*:

> Given a function $f\colon X\to Y$, the set $X$ is the domain of $f$; the set $Y$ is the codomain of $f$. (...)
>   The image of $f$ can be the same set as the codomain or it can be a proper subset of it; it is the whole codomain if and only if $f$ is a surjective function, and otherwise it is smaller.

*Sentence 1*: A function is a process or a relation that associates each element $x$ of a set $X$, **the domain of the function**, to a single element $y$ of another set $Y$ (possibly the same set), the codomain of the function.

*Sentence 2*: A function from $X$ to $Y$ often refers to a function that may have a proper subset of $X$ as domain.

Doesn't *sentence 1* contradict *sentence 2*?

Using *sentence 1*,
$$\tan\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$$
is nonsecial, since $\frac{\pi}{2}\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\tan\frac{\pi}{2}\notin\mathbb{R}$, but using *sentence 2*, it makes sense, as the domain of $\tan$ (when viewed as a function to $\mathbb{R}$) is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Since the **image** can be a proper or improper subset of the **codomain**, is there a mathematical term for a **proper subset** of the **domain**? Because this is exactly what is needed to get rid of the ambiguity.

Also, notice the word "open" in

> (...) the domain is a set of real numbers that contains a non-empty **open** interval (...)

in the first paragraph of this post. Why does it have to be open? And how would one even go about open intervals in case of functions acting on some natural numbers only?

Comment: The second sentence should read, "A partial function from $X$ to $Y$..."

Comment: If the underlying question is "can I rely on WIkipedia for precisely stated facts in mathematics" the answer is _No_!

Comment: So, as it seems, they used the fact that in real and complex analysis, a partial function is generally called simply a function.

Comment: This is what it means: The domain of a function $f:X\to Y$ is simply $X$, i.e. $\operatorname{Dom} f=X$. However, people like me are sometimes sloppy and write that $\tan$ is a function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$, even though it is actually a function from $\mathbb R\setminus \{k\cdot \pi/2:k\in\mathbb Z\}$ to $\mathbb R$

Comment: @kimchilover In my opinion, Wikipedia is still pretty good though

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch For some kinds of things, yes, and I often cite it  for basic background facts.  But in this case different articles contradict each other, as if they were separate textbooks with slightly different definitions.  So I would not rely on it for anything subtle, or depending on logical precision.

Comment: @Maximilian Janisch I don't think you're sloppy – I would say that, in general, $f\colon X\to Y$ is ambiguous and that it should be made clear whether one means that $f$ maps $X$ to $Y$ *or* that $f$ maps **from** $X$ to $Y$. Actually, the latter definition is often used in analysis, so $\tan\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ makes sense in the spirit of the latter definition.

Comment: In any language, words will have different meanings in different contexts.  This is also true in math.  But the literature should always specify any meanings that are ambiguous.

Comment: Generally when I see a function defined $f: X \rightarrow Y$ I assume that every element of $X$ maps to some unique element of $Y$.  If the definition is different, it should be spelled out.